# <a href> link navigation doesn't detect templates in JSF 2.0 Facelets pages

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:body>
    <title><ui:define name="title">Page 2</ui:define></title>
    <ui:composition template="template/common/commonLayout.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            This is the content of Page 2 page<br/>
            <h:form prependId="false">
                <h:commandButton id="goToIndex" value="Go to Index" action="index" />
            </h:form>
            <a href="index.xhtml">Index</a>
        </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>

</h:body>
</html>
```

I have two identical facelets pages: index.xhtml and page2.xhtml which link to each other. I also have a template file. There is no difference in the code between index and page2, apart from the name of the pages in the title, content text and commandButton values.

When I click on the goToIndex button implemented by the form to navigate to index.xhtml, everything works as expected: it goes to index.xhtml. However, when I click on the link implemented by the [a href] link to navigate to index.xhtml, it goes to index.xhtml but seems to ignore all the template settings for the page, including any form tag. The only thing rendered is the text confined in the "content" definition, but without any css formatting whatsoever.

This thing happens both way round. "index -> page2" and "pag2 -> index"

Any idea why this occurs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page that is called by `<a href ...>` isn't processed by the faces servlet and therefore not correctly translated and no css/js included.

Look in your *web.xml* and check how the faces servlet is mapped. There you might find something like:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You could change the pattern to:

```
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
```

Then all files with the xhtml prefix will be processed by the faces servlet. However this could cause problems if in you project the xhtml prefix is used for other purposes than facelets.

Another way would be to use `h:link` instead of `a:href`:

```
<h:link value="Index" outcome="index" >
```

where the outcome attribute takes the target page without .xhtml.